# Modify variable passed in a lambda function without global variable in button command

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any possible way to change already existing variable that I pass as an argument in lambda function without using global variable?

```
temp.btn['command'] = lambda temp=temp: last_btn = connect_buttons(temp, last_btn)
```

This throws an error since lambda cannot use assignment so return value seems out of question and it seems that global variables are "bad practice" not just in python. Since mutable object is list only afaik, I got an idea to make `last_btn` list with 1 element but I keep wondering if there really is no other option than these "ugly" solutions. Or are my assumptions wrong and one of these solutions is commonly used?

//added with edit:

```
def connect_buttons(btn1, btn2):    # takes the_button
    global cary
    if not (btn1 and btn2):
        if btn1:
            return btn1
        return btn2
    left = btn1
    right = btn2
    if isinstance(left, right_button):
        left = btn2
        right = btn1
    for a_line in cary:
        if a_line.start_button == left:
            cvs.after(0, cvs.delete, a_line.line_id)
    temp_id = cvs.create_line(left.x, left.y, right.x, right. y)
    cary.append(line_class(temp_id, left, right))
    return None
```

This is function made to connect 2 buttons with a line. It is possible that its crude as hell since I am still learning and not quite familiar with tkinter library. `right_button` and `left_button` are basically `tkinter.Buttons` with some extra information but each has its own class to make it easier to work with. There is possibility that my whole concept is wrong and should be made in some other way. I look forward to any information that can help me.

Comment: Can you show us your function? And its purpose? Your only choices are `global` or passing as parameter, AFAIK.

Comment: Try using `:=` instead of `=`. I think it only works on Python 3.8+. It is called the walrus operator. I am not sure if it will work but give it a shot

Comment: I did not manage to make it have effect on variable outside of the scope, can you share some example if you can make it work?

Comment: to be clear You are trying to change an existing variables' value? using lambda or is that not necessary? because one way would be to use dictionaries (I think) and redefine a key or sth

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change value of already existing variable.